# Discord bot on .NET, reacting on specific words

Tags: arrays, discord, bots, contains

The thing is that I wanted to create a bot that would react on a specific words sending by people in discord channel chat.

```
    private Task CowMooeing(SocketMessage msg)
    {
        string[] mooes = {"moo", "moooooo", "moooooooooo", "mooooooooooo"};

        foreach (string moo in mooes)
        {
            if (msg.Content.Contains(moo))
                msg.Channel.SendMessageAsync("hi there, you little COWard!");
        }
    }
```

but. If someone send "moo, moooo, moooo" in chat - the bot would react like multiple times on that.

i tried to replace msg.Content.Contains to msg.Content.Equals(). But in that case it won't work if someone adds an additional text like: i've said "mooo!"  - bot won't react on that. So I'm really stuck with that, and the only way I found to solve this problem is to duplicate mooes array in multiple time `if mooes[0], if mooes[1]` etc. But that's not the best way to do so.

With Regular expressions I've faced an issue where I couldn't use IsMatch or Match with msg.Content =(
Help me just a little bit, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just using the Linq Any approach as below? This will only send the one message as the Any will return true if any are found.

```
private Task CowMooeing(SocketMessage msg)
{
    string[] mooes = {"moo", "moooooo", "moooooooooo", "mooooooooooo"};
    if(mooes.Any(x => msg.Content.Contains(x))) {
         msg.Channel.SendMessageAsync("hi there, you little COWard!");
    }
}
```

I would also say look into regex regular expressions and they can be great for stuff like this

Comment: wow thanks! it needed msg.Content.Contains(x))) but everything is working now) thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help, all the best :)